# Diagonal of a numpy matrix without compute the entire matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a simple algebric problem and I would like to solve it with *numpy* (of course that I could solve it easily with *numba*, but that is not the point).

Let us consider a first random matrix **A** with size (m x n), with n a big value, and a second random matrix **B** with size (n x n).

```
A = np.random.random((1E6, 1E2))
B = np.random.random((1E2, 1E2))
```

We want to compute the following expression:

```
np.diag(np.dot(np.dot(A,B),B.T))
```

The problem is that the entire matrix is loaded to the memory and only then is extracted the diagonal. Is it possible to do this operation in a more efficient way?

Comment: Are the input matrices really random, or are they only examples?

Comment: This is a stackoverflow exercise, not a real problem. I choose random matrices to be the most general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would approach it from your starting expression

```
np.diag(np.dot(np.dot(A,B),B.T))
```

You can start by grouping terms:

```
np.diag(np.dot(A, np.dot(B,B.T)))
```

then only use the first relevant (square) part of A:

```
np.diag(np.dot(A[:B.shape[0], :], np.dot(B,B.T)))
```

and then avoid the extra multiplications (that will fall out of the diagonal), by doing the element-wise multiplications yourself:

```
np.sum( np.multiply(A[:B.shape[0], :].T, np.dot(B,B.T)), 0)
```

Comment: Woah! I just had to pull out a paper to understand why `np.sum(A.T * B, 0) == np.diag(A @ B)`. Mind blown

Comment: Since each element of `A @ B` is a dot prod of a row of A and a column of B, I transpose A and I do the dot products of rows (by element-wise multiplication and horizontal sum). This will only get you the elements that will fall on the diagonal. It's just a ~2.5x boost, the native matrix-matrix product is well-optimized.

Comment: Yeah. I just tested... you can skip the intermediate array creation using `np.einsum('ji,ij->j', ...)` and shave off a few microseconds that way, but I am not sure if that's worth it.

Comment: `H=np.squeeze(A[:B.shape[0],None,:]@(B@B.T)[:,:,None])` is even faster, but harder to understand.

Comment: @hpaulj :O that it indeed faster, amazing trick.

Answer (score 2):

1. Changed `(A*B)*B.T` to `A*(B*B.T)`
2. Multiplied only this part of A (`A[:B.shape[0]]`) that would result in the diagonal part of the matrix

```
import numpy as np
import time

A = np.random.random((1000_000, 100))
B = np.random.random((100, 100))

start_time = time.time()
result = np.diag(np.dot(np.dot(A, B), B.T))
print('Baseline: ', time.time() - start_time)

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    result2 = np.diag(np.dot(A[:B.shape[0]], np.dot(B, B.T)))
print('Optimized: ', (time.time() - start_time) / 100)
stop = 1

assert np.allclose(result, result2)
```

```
Baseline:  1.7957241535186768
Optimized:  0.00016015291213989258
```

Comment: Making use of the fact that `B` is so much smaller, clever!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
N = 1E6

A = np.random.random((N, 1E2))
B = np.random.random((1E2, 1E2))

result = 0;
for i in range(N):
  result += np.dot(np.dot(A[i,:], B[i,:])[i, :], B.T[i, :])

  # Replacing B.T[i, :] with B[:, i].T might be a little more efficient
```

---

#### Explanation:

Say we have: `K = np.dot(np.dot(A,B),B.T)`.

Then, `K[0,0] = (A[0, :] * B[:,0])[0, :] * B.T[:])`

- Let `X = (A[0, :] * B[:,0])`, which is the `[0, 0]` element of `np.dot(A,B)`
- Then `X[0, :] * B.T[:, 0]` is the `[0, 0]` element of `np.dot(np.dot(A,B),B.T)`
- Then `X[0, :] * B.T[:, 0]` = `(A[0, :] * B[:,0])[0, :] * B.T[:])`

We can also generalize this result to: `K[i,i] = (A[i, :] * B[:,i])[i, :] * B.T[:, i])`

Comment: Are you sure this is faster? Iterating over the longest axis doesn't sound fast to me...